# Is it possible to overwrite file permissions at destination with rsync?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I have 3 TB of data already copied with rsync.

My command:

```
rsync -avzP /home  <dest-user@dest-server-ip>:/backup/
```

Unfortunately the file permissions were not preserved. How can I overwrite the owners at destination, so that I don't need to copy everything again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want permissions to be preserved you must have **root** priviliges:

```
rsync -avzP /home  root@<dest-server-ip>:/backup/
```

Or:

```
sudo rsync -avzp --rsync-path "sudo rsync" /home <dest-user@dest-server-ip>:/backup/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the issue with the flag, use small -p not capital.

```
 -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
```